# Write unit-test for add-accessor of event

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events

I have a method which is called from a 3rd party assembly and serves as our application-entry point. This method raises our event `MyEvent`. In order to ensure the same event-handler is only registered once and only once, I implemented my own logic for `add` and `remove`:

```
class MyEditorExtension
{
    private EventHandler<MyArgs> myEvent
    public EventHandler<MyArgs> MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            if(this.myEvent == null || this.myEvent.GetInvocationList().All(x => !x.Equals(value))
                this.myEvent += value;
        }
        remove { this.myEvent -= value; }
    }

    // this method is called from ArcMap
    public void OnCreate()
    {
        ...
        MyEvent();
    }
}
```

`OnCreate` is quite huge and can´t safely be refactored into smaller, **testable** units. However I want to check if my event-definition really does what it is supposed to do. In order to do so I tried to register the exact same method twice and check if it was executed twice:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExtensionTest
{
    int numCalls;

    [Test]
    public void Test_Register_Handler_Twice()
    {
        var target = new MyExtension();
        target.MyEvent += myHandler;
        target.MyEvent += myHandler;
        target.MyEvent(new MyArgs());
        Assert.AreEqual(1, this.numCalls);
    }
    private void(MyArgs args) { this.numCalls ++; }
}
```

Of course the above won´t compile because I can´t raise an event outside its class. I´d also like to avoid introducing a `RaiseEvent`-method solely for the sake of testing the event.

So I wonder if there´s any way to achieve this, e.g. using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is possible using reflection. However this is quite hacky. In fact this is a common problem when testing legacy-code as this one. This solution was inspired by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000050/2528063

You have to know that an event is nothing but an `add`- and `remove`-method around a private (hidden) delegate-field, just like a property is nothing but a get- and set-method around a private (also hidden) backing-field. Having said this you can access that delegate, which usually has the exact same name as your event:

```
var delegateField = typeof(MyExtension).GetField("MyEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(target);
```

In our special case we have our own accessors and therefor the name of the delegate is provided directly within the source-cde of `MyExtension`. Thus we write this slightly different version:

```
var delegateField = typeof(MyExtension).GetField("myEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(target);
```

Now we have our backing delegate, which we can easily invoke:

```
delegateField?.DynamicInvoke(new MyArgs());
```

Of course we should add some sanity-checks, e.g. for the case the delegate was renamed and thus couldn´t be found, but I guess you get the point.